# Active Shape Models vs Active Appearance Models

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am implementing active ASM/AAM using OpenCV for segmentation of face images using OpenCV (to be further used in face recognition). I am pretty much done with the canonical implementation of ASM (as per T. Cootes papers) and result I get is not ideal, it does not always converge and when it does some boundaries are not captured, which I believe is a problem in the modeling of a local structure - i.e. gradient profile matching.

Now I am a bit unsure what to do next. ASM is a simpler and computationally less intensive algorithm compared to AAM. Should I continue improving ASM(say for example using 2D profiles rather than 1D profiles, or use different profile structure for different type of lanmarks) or get my hands straight on AAM?

Edit: Also, what are the papers you could recommend that improve on the original work by T.Cootes? I know there are so many of them, but maybe there are techniques that are considered canonical today?

Answer (score 7):

You can find clarifications and implemented AAM whith 2D profiles in the book "Mastering OpenCV with Practical Computer Vision Projects" by Packt Publishing 2012. A lot of projects described in this book are open source and can be downloaded here: [GitHub](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code). They are more advanced than T.Cootes implementation.

I can say that AAM (as existing implementation you can look also at [vosm](http://www.visionopen.com/downloads/open-source-software/vosm/)) have good convergence (better than ASM) only if you train it on the same man (very good results for example for FRANCK (Talking Face Video) sequence) in other cases ASM works better.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I actually have this book, but I only had a look at chapter 7. Having looking at Chapter 6 now I can see they use patches, which I believe are 2D profiles you mention here. I will have to have a look closer at the implementation to understand it, because unfortunately I cannot make much sense from the book itself, it's not as detailed as the scientific papers describing the original technique.There's also paper "Active Appearance Models Revisited. Iain Matthews and Simon Baker" which many people quote, so I will have a look at that.

Comment: You can also take a look at Deformable Model Library DeMoLib, http://staff.estem-uc.edu.au/roland/research/demolib-home/ by Dr. Roland Goecke

Comment: updated link of demolib: https://rolandgoecke.net/research/demolib-home/